# I got this error when i shoot the mail through mailgun.org in laravel8

Tags: laravel

Expected response code 354 but got code "421", with message "421 Domain sandbox4412497ba418406ba96c4a5332029424.mailgun.org is not allowed to send: Sandbox subdomains are for test purposes only. Please add your own domain or add the address to authorized recipients in Account Settings.

Answer (score 1):

Like the message says you are using the test domain in mailgun.com. When using test domains you must add email addresses that are allowed to receive emails.

You can go to domain settings in mailgun add add recipient address to "[Authorized Recipients](https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/217531258-Authorized-Recipients)".